# Highcharts not working in iOS devices inside Lightning Framework in Salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, mobile, lightning-experience, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to represent some data inside Lightning framework in the Salesforce1 app. But the graph is not at all being displayed in iOS devices. (*used strict mode*).

The parent div enclosing the Highcarts is displayed, but the charts are not displayed. The graph is rendering properly in Android devices.

Also, while tetsing in the browser simulator (here, I'm using Chrome, its coming, but when you open the same on device, it's not coming at all)

Can anyone who has worked on Highcharts in Lightning framework give some insights on how to fix this issue?

[image: Please see the screenshot of the error (in iPad)]

Please see the screenshot of the error which pops up when taking the app in Safari browser (iPad) too.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but this link https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1551 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779580/highcharts-graph-not-visible-on-ipad seem to point to an outdated version of iOS being used?

Comment: Hi Andy,
The current version of the iOS in the iPad I'm using is 9.3.2
I've added the screenshot of the error when accessing the app in Safari browser in iPad above.